# compiling a method as if it was part of another class

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

Im looking for something that can compile a method as if it was in a different class so that i can Inject a method that uses internal fields and types without having to manually change the Operand values.

For instance if we need to get a value for debugging:

```
class bla{
internal string importantValue;
...
public void onInitialize(){
    ...
    //this is where the compiler should be made to think it is
}
}
```

and the code that goes into the compiler

```
public void onInitialize(){ //code to be compiled as if it were in that method
    File.WriteAllText("usefulString.txt",importantValue.toString());
}
```

and then we can get the il of the compiled output and insert it into *bla.onInitialize* so that we now can get our value

Comment: is using `partial` classes an option?

Comment: Are you asking how to take an arbitrary bit of code and insert it into a separate pre-compiled assembly as a member of a class in that assembly?

Comment: @eim64 I don't understand exactly what you need. Can you try to explain it? If yes, I'm sure I can help you.  Do you need to generate method that can read internal members of a `class`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the example given, making onInitialize() protected, then constructing an override in another class would work.

Alternatively make the body of the method a delegate defined at class level - then set a different delegate in your code to make it do something else.

Comment: im looking for something that can get all methods and fields

Comment: You are looking to use a testing technique called Fakes, which allows you to arbitrarily change code from what the author intended and make it do something else. This is typically used to isolate code to allow unit testing to occur - see Microsoft Fakes for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get what you want to achive and I think there is a simpler way.

But if I understand from your question title, you want to compile your class `bla` (for example) and you want that in method `onInitialize` will be added new code (that doesn't exit there) in compile time. It it true?

For this you have a several ways. I'll describe two of them.

1. You can use library like [StaticProxy.Fody](https://github.com/BrunoJuchli/StaticProxy.Fody). This lib let you intercept method and inject into it whatever you want. So in your example, you intercept `onInitialize` method and you add to it this code `File.WriteAllText("usefulString.txt",importantValue.toString());`
   All of this in compile time. After you compile the code your ouput dll will contain this injected code.
2. Second option is to compile your code regulary and after that you can use `Mono.Cecil` to read your compiled dll and write code that will add whatever you want to where you want, (in our example, add `File.WriteAllText etc.` to `onInitialize`) after you save this dll it will contain the new injected code.

Both of the options are simple way to add code in static manner (aka compile time and not runtime).